# On which thread does a non blocking async method runs

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, nonblocking, c#-5.0

We say that, if an awaited expression is not complete then an async method
pauses and returns to the caller.

Once the awaited expression is complete, it resumes it execution.

On which context it resumes is dictated by ConfigureAwait.

But what happens in between pausing and returning to the caller and resuming after the awaited expression is completed.

Where does the awaited expression execute mean while ?

On a Thread Pool thread or UI's thread.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // will resume on UI's context.
    button.Content = await GetString().ConfigureAwait(true);
}

private async Task<string> GetString()
{
    // where does this section of code runs ?
    return await Task.Delay(3000).ContinueWith(x => "Async Content");
}
```

Comment: `GetString` is scheduled on a ThreadPool thread and `TaskAwaiter` is returned to keep a reference. If `TaskAwaiter` is completed before code jumps out of current state then the result is returned and code progresses to next await. If it is not completed then `TaskAwaiter` is waiting for the task and continuation on await is configured for the task.

Answer (score 0):

Neither thread pool nor UI thread. It does not execute at all.  When Task.Delay is called, the Delay method creates a Timer and both GetString and Button_Click return.
After 3000 milliseconds the Timer callback gets executed on some thread pool thread.  It completes the task and schedules task continuations, and the rest of code in GetString and Button_Click is executed on respective threads.